# 301 redirection not redirecting to the right URL without a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have to manually redirect few URLs in my website1 to website2.

Below is my code in the `.htaccess` file of website1

```
Redirect 301 /post1/ https://www.website2.com/post1
```

When I enter `https://www.website1.com/post1/` in the browser it's being redirected to `https://www.website2.com/post1` successfully, as expected.

But, When I enter `https://www.website1.com/post1` in the browser it's being redirected to `https://www.website2.compost1`, the slash is missing after `https://www.website2.com`

What could be done to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 Redirect URLs in this particular order solved it.

```
Redirect 301 /post1 https://www.website2.com/post1

Redirect 301 /post1/ https://www.website2.com/post1
```

Comment: You shouldn't need two to accomplish this. The one with the trailing slash removed should've been sufficient. You're simply adding an extra redirect for your server to run prior to loading.

Comment: @Joe I tried, but it didn't work. That's the reason I had to add both.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in a single rule using `RedirectMatch` that uses a regex to make trailing slash optional as this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(post1)/?$ https://www.website2.com/$1
```

**Added benefit** is avoiding repeat of `post1` in source and target by using a capture group in source and using back-reference `$1` in target.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing `/` from the Redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /post1 https://www.website2.com/post1
```

This redirect then works for both versions of the URL. See testing link [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=b450bee7-0bd8-5a89-8b8f-453f4cb87132).

Comment: Did this help you @Anirudh ?